# Reference nuget package project from another nuget package project in same solution

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I am creating couple of .NET Standard 1.6 libraries that I want to publish as Nuget packages.  They share a common libary that is a 3rd project in the same solution as the first two.  The shared library has no value by itself, but I am assuming that if I want people to use both of these two libaries in the same project I should publish the shared library as a Nuget package as well.  If I don't I am worried about multiple copies of the same shared library "colliding" or not properly warning when there are version mismatch issues.

Am I correct that the shared library needs to be a Nuget package as well?  Is there a way to reference the shared library as Nuget package, but use is as if it was a project reference when developing / debugging the 2 main libraries in this solution?  If I had to publish to Nuget.org and wait for the package be propagate through the Nuget.org system before using a changed version in a debug session that is REALLY going to slow down development.  Note that these are .NET Standard projects.  I found [How to reference related projects in the same solution when Nuget packages are the required output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135689/how-to-reference-related-projects-in-the-same-solution-when-nuget-packages-are-t) but that doesn't seem to work with .NET Standard (getting errors during pack) and I am also not sure if .NET Standard not using nuspec files anymore also would cause a problem.

Comment: any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, please let me know the latest info about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I am also not sure if .NET Standard not using nuspec files anymore also would cause a problem.

The .NET Standard still using .nuspec files, and using old school `nuget pack` and `a .nuspec` will resolve this issue.

As per document [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x):

> NuGet dependencies of the packed project are added to the .nuspec
>   file, so they're properly resolved when the package is installed.
>   Project-to-project references aren't packaged inside the project.
>   Currently, **you must have a package per project if you have
>   project-to-project dependencies**.

So, to include project-to-project references in NuGet packages, you need **manually maintain a `.nuspec` file and add dependencies**. You can refer to the [Create .NET Standard packages with Visual Studio 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2015) for detail info.

Besides, dasMulli has provided a simpler way to do this by involving adding and hooking up a custom target :

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);IncludeP2PAssets</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\testprivatelib\testprivatelib.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="IncludeP2PAssets">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="$(OutputPath)\testprivatelib.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The source code comes from: ["donet pack" is not including project references](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3959)

Comment: it returns me error that testprivatelib not found on the path bin\Release\netstandard2.0 although file is there, i dont understand why?